# How to implement the following voice recording library in angular latest version?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am trying to use the following library to record voice audio in angular.

https://github.com/killroywashere/ng-audio-recorder

This is the code sample to use it:

```
import { NgAudioRecorderService, OutputFormat } from 'ng-audio-recorder';
...

@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {

    constructor(private audioRecorderService: NgAudioRecorderService) {
    
        this.audioRecorderService.recorderError.subscribe(recorderErrorCase => {
            // Handle Error
        })
    }
    
    startRecording() {
        this.audioRecorderService.startRecording();
    }
    
    stopRecording() {
         this.audioRecorderService.stopRecording(outputFormat).then((output) => {
            // do post output steps
         }).catch(errrorCase => {
             // Handle Error
         });
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't specify what outputFormat and how to playback the audio recording. Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the output format like this:

```
onStopRecording() {
        this.busyRecording = false;
        this.recordingStarted = false;
        let outputFormat = OutputFormat.WEBM_BLOB;
 
        this.audioRecorderService.stopRecording(outputFormat).then((output: Blob) => {
            this.blobData = output;

            this.populatePlayer(output);
         }).catch(errrorCase => {
             this.toast.error(errrorCase);
         });

    }
```

Note: this.blobData is of type Blob.

Notice that we forced output to be a Blob. The output format either have WEBM_BLOB or WEBM_BLOB_URL types.

The ng-audio-recorder.service.d.ts will complain since we changed the output type, but you can go to this service and change it to a BLOB. If this doesnt work you can tell Angular to ignore those kinds of errors.